# easy_install-3.2.exe vs easy_install.exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, easy-install

For Python 3.2, What is recommended: `easy_install-3.2` or `easy_install`?

Why two execs? What's the difference?

One more question: `distribute` or `setuptools`? `setuptools` is obviously not working on 
Intel Win64/python3.2 (or not available as of writing this post).

Comment: If you have two questions, please write two different questions so that other people can search them on the site and benefit from their response.

Answer (score 3):

Answering just to the first question.

Regarding `easy_install`, since you might have multiple `python` versions installed, you might have also different `easy_install` versions installed (one for each `python` version). In that case, `easy_install` will be the default version and `easy_install-X.Y` will be the version to install new packages for `python-X.Y`.

Answer (score 2):

You use the easy_install that is for the installation of Python where you want to install it. In most cases, both easy_install and easy_install-3.2 will be the same program and install to the same installation of Python.

You can install the same version of Python in different places, then you need to run the easy_install from the right place. You can also install several versions of Python in one place, and then you need to use the right version.

Always use Distribute in preference to Setuptools.